# How to delete Kubernetes PVC finalisers pv-protection?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks, kubectl

I am trying to delete the finalisers in the PV by issuing kubectl patch command and it deletes partially leaving behind Kubernetes.io/pv-protection

Described the PVC and able to see two entries

Finalisers: [Kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com]

Command executed: kubectl patch pv pvname -p '{"metadata":{"finalisers":null}}'

It removes only external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com

Any idea how to remove the pv-protection finaliser?

Thanks in advance

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If you delete a PVC in active use by a Pod, the PVC is not removed immediately. PVC removal is postponed until the PVC is no longer actively used by any Pods. Also, if an admin deletes a PV that is bound to a PVC, the PV is not removed immediately. PV removal is postponed until the PV is no longer bound to a PVC.

You can see that a PVC is protected when the PVC's status is Terminating and the Finalizers list includes kubernetes.io/pvc-protection

Looks like your PVC is still being actively used by some pod.

Same is the case with PV. PV Protection prevents accidental deletion of PersistentVolume objects. When a PersistentVolume object is in use by a Pod, Kubernetes adds the pv-protection finalizer.

First delete the pod and then attempt to delete PVC and then the PV.